# Playing with white space tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The following whitespace tags should all be synonymized/merged:

[whitespace](/questions/tagged/whitespace) **× 757**
[spaces](/questions/tagged/spaces) **× 219**
[removing-whitespace](/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace) **× 66**

The following should be considered:

[space](/questions/tagged/space) **× 303**
[spacing](/questions/tagged/spacing) **× 155**

These two tags tend to allude to spacing between HTML elements, or objects whether it be related to graphics or otherwise. Most often when tagged along with CSS or HTML, it is meant to refer to either padding or margin, depending on context. In most other cases, these two are use meta-like. I think [space](/questions/tagged/space) (which in a few cases is also used to refer to outer space) should be synonymized, and [spacing](/questions/tagged/spacing) should be destroyed to avoid confusion, as it is a very general term that applies to a very wide range of things.

Also, we could possibly consider these two:

[nbsp](/questions/tagged/nbsp) **× 23**
[non-breaking-spaces](/questions/tagged/non-breaking-spaces) **× 13**

These tags appear a bit meta-like and should be explained in the context of the post. It's not really a good "category" in terms of tags. It should be a synonym so that it doesn't get recreated later.

Comment: I'd see `whitespace` and `html-spacing` as the major tags, with nbsp destroyed.  I don't think it should be synonymized as it's not clear anything matches, and it can be blacklisted if it needs to be prevented from coming back.

Comment: So much whitespace. Gotta see it all.

Comment: *Some* of those `nbsp` questions might be good candidates for [tag:html-entities] instead.